# sonata_type_model_list how to delete image after select

Tags: sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata, sonata-media-bundle

Is it possible to delete a media after you have selected it (also in database)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Many-to-One or One-to-One relations with sonata_type_model_list**

   ```
          ->add('client', 'sonata_type_model_list', [
                       'btn_add'       => $this->trans('admin.button.add_client'),
                       'btn_list'      => $this->trans('admin.button.list'),
                       'btn_delete'    => 'Delete button',
                       'btn_catalogue' => $this->translationDomain,
                       'label'         => $this->trans('admin.label.client'),
                       'required'      => true,
               ], [
                       'placeholder'   => $this->trans('admin.placeholder.no_client'),
               ])
   ```

   [image]

   The line `'btn_delete'    => 'delete button'` gives you delete button 
   right of you one-to-one entity. 
   In this example I use an entity ClientCard which has one-to-one relation to Client entity.
2. **List view**.
   By default you have delete button in list view. 
   [image]
   Delete - is one of the batch actions. If you want to disable this action (and all other as well) you have to overwrite `getBatchActions` method

   ```
   /**
    * @return null
    */
   public function getBatchActions()
   {
       return null;
   }
   ```
3. **Edit mode**. 
   By default you have delete button in edit mode. 
   [image] 
   If you want completely disable the delete action, then you can overwrite `configureRoutes` method:

   ```
   /**
    * @param RouteCollection $collection
    */
   protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollection $collection)
   {
       $collection->remove('delete');
   }
   ```

Hope it will help.